# ILS Antenna and Matched RG142 Cable

Tags: voltage, signal, cables

> The voltage signal received at an instrument landing system (ILS) antenna is
> 5.0 V. A RG142 cable (data sheet is provided) is used to deliver the signal to
> the avionic bay which is 90 m away from the ILS antenna. Given that the
> ILS antenna is operating at 100 MHz and both the antenna and the load are
> matched to the RG142 cable, calculate
> i) the time-delay caused by this RG142 cable.
> ii) the delivered voltage signal at the avionic bay

So I have this question as part of a past paper and I'm not quite sure how to do the second part. I have calculated the time delay to be 432ns using, time delay = distance/(velocity propagation * c).

How would I handle the second part? I have also included the data sheet which could be used.

Thanks for any input.

[image]

Comment: You know the operating frequency, the length of the cable and, from the data sheet, the nominal loss of the cable at your frequency of interest.  That's all you need to figure out the voltage drop in the cable.

Comment: okay thank you, I'll have a go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *ii) the delivered voltage signal at the avionic bay*

The signal is 100 MHz (as stated) and, the RG393 cable (very similar to RG142 cable) has an attenuation of 0.066 dB/metre at 100 MHz so, over 90 metres, the attenuation will be 5.94 dB.